# In Google Sheets, How would I highlight only one max value in one column per unique row in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

So essentially, I have one column with URLs (which can repeat but have a list of URLs in them), and next to that I have a number. I am trying to select the max number for all  instances of the particular URL, and then highlight those max value instances.

An Example would be:

```
URL | Number
url1 | 10
url1 | 20
url1 | 50
url2 | 5
url2 | 100
url3 | 25
url3 | 26
url4 | 100
url4 | 10
```

So what would a formula in the conditional highlighting for the sheet look like, in order to capture each unique URL's max value in the second column?

Thanks in advance for anything you can provide here. I was trying to use something like `=ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(B:B=B9, F:F)))` but it ended up highlighting everything when placed into the conditional custom formula in Google sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula in ***Custom Rule***.

```
=(B:B=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,$A1))*(A:A=$A1)*($A1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was not getting the result with the previous formula, but yours worked like a charm. It did take a while to process all of the calculations in the sheet with nearly 50K rows, but worth it!